# Filtering an event for a node in a context menu?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a context menu in a TableView with some advanced controls to be interacted with. It's a little annoying because the moment you click on a control within the context menu, it does the event but it also fires off the event that makes the context menu go away.

How exactly do I implement a filter for the context menu within that control?

```
Pane filterPane = buildFilterPane();

CustomMenuItem menuItem = new CustomMenuItem();

menuItem.contentProperty().set(filterPane);
// I want all click events inside the filterPane to only be heard by the filterPane
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
menuItem.setHideOnClick(false);
```

Comment: Just tried per your suggestion. Its still not quite working. I'll put an SSCCE up tomorrow.

Comment: The solution of James_D does work. So what exactly isn't working for you? Please provide full sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of James_D's solution. I just created it because I was curious to find out how you can change the visibility of the table columns by selecting the columns in a context menu while the context menu remains open, so that you can select multiple columns.

```
public class TableWithContextMenu extends Application {

    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList( 
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"));
    final HBox hb = new HBox();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(550);

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

        // build context menu 
        // --------------------------------
        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("Closing Item");
        item1.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Clicked: " + e));

        CustomMenuItem item2 = new CustomMenuItem(new Label("Stay Open Item"));
        item2.setHideOnClick(false);
        item2.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Clicked: " + e));

        CustomMenuItem item3 = new CustomMenuItem(new Label("Manually Closing Item"));
        item3.setHideOnClick(false);
        item3.setOnAction(e -> {
            System.out.println("Clicked: " + e);
            contextMenu.hide();
        });

        CheckBox firstNameCheckBox = new CheckBox("First Name");
        firstNameCheckBox.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional( firstNameCol.visibleProperty());
        CustomMenuItem item4 = new CustomMenuItem( firstNameCheckBox);
        item4.setHideOnClick(false);

        CheckBox lastNameCheckBox = new CheckBox("Last Name");
        lastNameCheckBox.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional( lastNameCol.visibleProperty());
        CustomMenuItem item5 = new CustomMenuItem( lastNameCheckBox);
        item5.setHideOnClick(false);

        CheckBox emailCheckBox = new CheckBox("email");
        emailCheckBox.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional( emailCol.visibleProperty());
        CustomMenuItem item6 = new CustomMenuItem( emailCheckBox);
        item6.setHideOnClick(false);

        CustomMenuItem item7 = new CustomMenuItem(new CheckBox("Custom Action"));
        item7.setHideOnClick(false);
        item7.setOnAction(e -> {System.out.println( e);});

        contextMenu.getItems().addAll(item1, item2, item3, new SeparatorMenuItem(), item4, item5, item6, new SeparatorMenuItem(), item7);

        // set context menu
        table.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll( table);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName) {
            email.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is interesting. I clicked the "Stay Open Item" and it works and behaves as expected, but those checkboxes are closing the entire contextMenu once they are clicked, even though their setHideOnClick() are set to false.

Comment: That's odd. It works for me. Which Java version are you using? I use 1.8.0_25. I hope you don't start the application with some parameters that might influence the behavior.

Comment: It looks like my Eclipse is using 1.8.0_20 for the JRE, and I'm using Windows 8.1. Maybe I should upgrade and I'll let you know.

Comment: Okay I pointed Eclipse to use 1.8.0_25 which is the default installation for my computer. But it is still behaving the same way with the sample code above. Again, clicking the checkboxes should not cause the ContextMenu to disappear right? What OS are you using? Could this be a Windows JVM issue?